# How to Bind column of a table in array and display result one by one on button click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, arraylist

I have created method to store column value of Questions from Question table into array and now I wanted to display in a label one by one on button click event.

```
public ArrayList BindDataToArray()
{
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    con = new SqlConnection(str);
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select Question from  Questions", con);
    con.Open();
    adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
    {
        list.Add(dtrow);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You wanted to display WHAT?

Comment: Question which i'l be getting from Questions table on button click event one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click"  
            CommandArgument="0" />//dEFINATION OF BUTTON ON ASPX PAGE

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
     list=BindDataToArray();
     int I=( Convert.ToInt32(Button1.CommandArgument));
     if (I < list.Count)
     {
          Label1.Text = list[I] as string; //Label in which u want to show message
          Button1.CommandArgument = (I + 1).ToString();
     }
     else
     {
         Label1.Text = "eND OF LIST";
         Button1.Enabled = false;
     }
}

public ArrayList BindDataToArray()
{
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    con = new SqlConnection(str);
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select Question from  Questions", con);
    con.Open();
    adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
    {
        list.Add(dtrow["Question"].ToString());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but it not showing question in label?no error

Comment: its show the data that u return frim your function BindDataToArray() nothing else

Comment: modify ur BindDataToArray() like this..
  foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
    {
        list.Add(dtrow["Queastion"].ToString());
    }

Answer (score 0):

Save the list in to the session

initialize a int with value = 0 and store this also in the session.

when the button is clicked

get the list and int from the session

update the label with the list[index] value where index is the int.

increment the int by one and resave it in the session.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for [gridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) control of asp.net.
Example http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1594-how-to-populate-gridview-from-code-behind.aspx

Comment: no this is for grid view binding once at a time but i wanted to bind question from questions table and display it in the label one by one on the click event of button..

Answer (score 0):

```
// in Aspx Page
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" 
            CommandArgument="1" /><asp:Label
           ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
//in Aspx.cs

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            list = BindDataToArray();
            int I = (Convert.ToInt32(Button1.CommandArgument.Count()));
            //int I = (Convert.ToInt32(Button1.CommandArgument));
            if (I < list.Count)
            {
                Label1.Text = list[I] as string; //Label in which u want to show message
                Button1.CommandArgument = (I + 1).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "eND OF LIST";
                Button1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        public ArrayList BindDataToArray()
        {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //con = new SqlConnection(con);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SurveyName FROM tblSurveyName", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows) { list.Add(dtrow["SurveyName"].ToString()); }
            return list;
        }
```